# Beziehung zwischen dem Warten von Maschinen und dem Warten auf ein Ereignis?

Tags: etymology, difference

Warten im Sinne von Instandhaltung von Maschinen (engl. "maintenance") scheint für mich wenig mit "auf etwas warten" zu tun zu haben, ist aber das gleiche Wort.

Gibt es da eine Verbindung? Wenn ja, welche und warum?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eine Warte ist ein anderes Wort für einen Wachturm oder eine Beobachtungsplattform. Auf einer Warte steht ein Wärter, und was macht er dort? Richtig: Er wartet. Der Wärter passt also auf etwas auf und er hält Ausschau nach Bedrohungen.

Er sorgt also dafür, dass alles in Ordnung ist. „Warten“ bedeutet daher: den geregelten Ablauf sichern.

Aber in Wahrheit sitzt der Wärter nur rum und tut nichts. Er „erwartet“ ein außergewöhnliches Ereignis. „Warten“ bedeutet daher auch: solange nichts tun, bis etwas passiert.

Comment: Ah, verstehe. Dann ist Softwarewartung also ein ziemliches Unwort, da es notwendigerweise proaktiv ist.

Comment: Bei der Softwarewartung werden Bugs behoben ohne die eigentliche Funktionalität des Programms zu verändern oder gar zu erweitern. Um Bugs beheben zu können müssen sie bekannt sein. Also: Zuerst einen Bug entdecken, erst danach das Programm warten (den Bug beheben). Für mich ist das nicht proaktiv. Proaktiv wäre es, wenn du den Sourcecode nach möglichen Schwachstellen durchsuchst, die noch gar nicht zu unerwünschtem Verhalten geführt haben und diese Schwachstellen ausbesserst bevor das unerwünschte Verhalten auftritt. Das ist aber nicht das was ich unter Wartung verstehe.

Comment: Genau das tue ich :) Aber doch, Debuggen kann als Wartung aufgefasst werden. Davon abgesehen zählt zur Wartung im weitesten Sinne auch das hinzufügen neuer Features.

Comment: Wartungsarbeiten am Aufzug sind sicher nicht darauf beschränkt, darauf zu warten, dass etwas schiefgeht (hoffe ich zumindest :-)). Somit ist zumindest die Moderne Bedeutung des Wortes durchaus nicht nur reaktiv zu verstehen.

Comment: 1. ist nicht das Wort proaktiv, so dass man nicht "es" sagen kann, sondern die Wartung, also "sie". Wenn überhaupt. Gewartet werden Maschinen, bei denen es Verschleiß gibt, oder man muss Schmieröl nachfüllen. Einen von Beginn vorhandenen Fehler auszubessern ist "flicken" alias "patchen". Allerdings bin ich mal einer Software begegnet, die temporäre Dateien anlegte, und bei fil168.tmp oder so hängte sich das Programm regelmäßig auf. Löschte man alle alten, temporären Dateien, so lief es wieder sauber weiter. Diese regelmäßigen Löschungen könnte man als Wartung bezeichnen, oder die Defragment.

Answer (score 16):

Beide Begriffe haben nicht nur dieselbe Etymologie, sondern es handelt sich um das gleiche Wort, das seit dem Althochdeutschen neben der gebräuchlicheren Bedeutung *„harren“* immer auch die Bedeutung *„pflegen“* hatte:

> **warten** Vb. verweilen, bleiben, bis etw. Bestimmtes eintritt, harren, pflegen, *ahd.* wartēn (8. Jh.), *mhd.* **warten:** spähen, (aus)schauen (nach), wahrnehmen, Anwartschaft haben, sich vorsehen, sorgen, pflegen <sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=wartung&view=1)</sup>

Erst in der Substantivierung wird in der modernen Hochsprache die Bedeutung der *„Wartung“* von dem *„Warten“* getrennt, wenn auch nicht gänzlich (siehe *„Erwartung“*).

Comment: @bitmask: Die gleiche Parallelität gibt's im Englischen auch, wenn man sich etwas ältere Literatur anschaut. "To wait on s.b." = "jmd. bedienen" und da fällt mir gleich noch "aufwarten" im Deutschen ein. Oh, und "Lady in waiting" im Englischen für eine "Hofdame".

Comment: Der "waiter" (Kellner) ist ja auch noch im modernen Englisch anzutreffen. Und dessen Aufgabe ist weder das Warten auf ein Ereignis, noch das Warten von Maschinen, sondern die Bedienung der Gäste.

Comment: Man könnte sagen, der waiter wartet auf die Wünsche des Gastes. Und man könnte wohl auch sagen der Maschinist, der eine Maschine wartet, wartet auf ein Nichtfunktionieren von Teilen. Als guter Maschinist beugt er solchem Nichtfunktionieren durch regelmäßige Kontrolle vor. - So könnte man warten (auf) vielleicht hinbiegen zu (eine Maschine) warten. Bin mir aber nicht sicher, ob das die wirkliche Etymologie und Semantik ist.