# Können Gegenstände warten?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Seit knapp einem Jahr lebe ich nicht mehr in Wien, sondern in St. Pölten, habe aber dennoch viel in Wien zu tun. Daher fahre ich oft mit dem Zug zwischen beiden Städten hin und her und habe auch eine Ermäßigungskarte, die bei den ÖBB »Vorteilscard« heißt. Meine Vorteilscard läuft im Jänner aus, daher haben mir die ÖBB einen Brief geschickt, in dem ich darauf aufmerksam gemacht werde, dass jetzt ein günstiger Zeitpunkt wäre, eine neue Vorteilscard zu beantragen.

In diesem Brief steht unter anderem dieser Satz:

> Ihre neue Vorteilscard wartet schon auf Sie!

Nun hege ich schon mal große Zweifel daran, dass eine Karte, die ich noch gar nicht bestellt habe, überhaupt existiert. Daher wird sie sich schon aus diesem Grund schwer tun irgend etwas zu tun, und sei es nur irgendwo faul herumzuliegen und zu warten. Aber sehen wir mal über dieses Detail hinweg. Angenommen die Karte würde tatsächlich schon hergestellt worden sein und jetzt irgendwo rumliegen:

### Kann man dieses *rumliegen* als »warten« bezeichnen?

In der Frage »[Beziehung zwischen dem Warten von Maschinen und dem Warten auf ein Ereignis?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/5130/1487)« wurde bereits geklärt, dass es zwei Ausprägungen des Wartens gibt, die aber nur zwei Seiten derselben Medaille sind (Details siehe dort):

- etwas instand halten
- das Eintreten eines bestimmten Ereignisses wahrnehmen wollen

Meine zukünftige Karte wird sicher nichts in Schuss halten, daher kann mit dem Warten nur gemeint sein, dass meine Karte Beobachtungen macht, um das Eintreten eines Ereignisses feststellen zu können. Das erwartete Ereignis ist der Eingang meiner Bestellung, welche meine Karte überhaupt erst aus dem Reich der Fantasie ins wirkliche Sein befördern könnte, aber dieser Widerspruch soll ja ausdrücklich nicht das Thema meiner Frage sein.

### Meine Definition von »Warten«:

Ich glaube, dass mit

> jemand wartet auf etwas

gemeint ist, dass jemand auf irgend eine Weise Ausschau nach einem Signal hält, das ihm anzeigt, dass sich ab dem Eintreten dieses Signals etwas verändern wird:

- Wenn ich auf einen Bus warte, stehe ich an einer Haltestelle und schaue in die Richtung, aus welcher der Bus üblicherweise kommt. Das Auftauchen des Busses hinter einer Wegbiegung ist das Signal auf das ich warte. Es zeigt mir an, dass ich bald in den Bus einsteigen kann.
- Wenn ich auf einen Anruf warte, richte ich meine Aufmerksamkeit auf erhöhte Weise auf die Laute, die mein Telefon von sich geben kann. Läutet es, hebe ich ab und spreche. Das würde ich natürlich auch tun, wenn ich auf keinen speziellen Anruf gewartet hätte. Der Unterschied besteht darin, dass ich beim Warten meine Aufmerksamkeit zumindest zeitweilig verstärkt auf das Telefon lenke. Wenn ich auf einen Anruf warte, werde ich auch dafür sorgen, dass ich das Telefon jederzeit hören kann. Jemand, der sein Telefon in einen ausgepolsterten Kasten stellt und sich Kopfhörer mit lauter Musik aufsetzt, wartet nicht auf einen Anruf.
- Sogar wenn ich auf den Tod warte, weil ich vielleicht krank und des langen Lebens müde bin, tue ich dabei aktiv etwas: Ich lenke meine Aufmerksamkeit auf Anzeichen, die das Ende meines Lebens ankündigen könnten. Und wenn diese Anzeichen auftauchen, werde ich mich ihnen entweder bewusst hingeben, oder mich dagegen wehren. Ich werde also irgend etwas tun. Das ist etwas anderes als ein unerwarteter Tod, der mich z.B im Fall eines plötzlichen Unfalls aus heiterem Himmel erwischt, und der mir keine Möglichkeit gibt, ihm mit irgend einer Aktion zu begegnen.

In allen Fällen, die mir als Beispiele einfallen, tut die wartende Person beim Warten aktiv etwas (nämlich im weitesten Sinn: Beobachten). Diese Fähigkeit traue ich einer Plastikkarte jedoch nicht zu.

Daher meine konkrete Frage:

Ist meine obige Definition zu eng gefasst? Kann man auch auf etwas warten, ohne die Bereitschaft zu haben, selbst auf das Eintreten des erwarteten Signals mit irgendwelchen Aktivitäten zu reagieren?

Comment: Ich halte die Frage gewissermaßen für sinnlos, wenn man sie am genannten Beispiel festmacht. Sicherlich ist es interessant, zu ergründen, ob es sich beim *Warten* um eine aktive oder passive Tätigkeit handelt. Im genannten Beispiel, in dem die Vorteilscard auf den Kunden wartet, wurde aber einfach das Produkt ein Stück weit personifiziert - möglicherweise, um es gegenüber den realen Personen in den Vordergrund zu heben. Schließlich soll sich der Kunde nicht an ÖBB-Sachbearbeiter Anton Meierlein erinnern, sondern an die ÖBB-Vorteilscard. Wenn man nun von dieser Personifizierungsidee ...

Comment: ... ausgeht, wird schnell klar, dass dem personifizierten Gegenstand prinzipiell jede Aktivität zugeschrieben werden kann, die auch eine Person ausführen könnte - das ist ja mit der Sinn der Personifizierung. Und damit wird es auch vollkommen egal, ob wir über *warten*, *schlafen*, *sprechen* oder *rennen* reden.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das wäre doch eine gute Antwort. Warum schreibst du das als Kommentar?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich hatte darüber nachgedacht, das als Antwort zu schreiben, aber wie schon im Kommentar umrissen, ist es ja eigentlich keine Antwort auf die Frage (sondern eher eine Erklärung, wieso die Frage in ihrer aktuellen Form nicht zum Beispiel passt).

Comment: Die Verschiebung der Aufmerksamkeit vom Warten auf den Bus auf das Warten auf Signale, die auf den Bus hindeuten, verändert die Lage. Man kann auf Signale warten und das Signalisierte und oft folgt das eine aus dem anderen. Man kann aber auch auf Ereignisse warten, die keine Signale vorrausschicken und man kann emotional unbeteiligt warten. Beim Warten auf den Bus kann man Tetris spielen, und nach kurzem den Bus vergessen, und wenn er dann kommt und höflich hupt aufschrecken - man wird dennoch erklären können, auf den Bus gewartet zu haben.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Wortschmiede in der Werbeindustrie sind darauf bestrebt, ein Produkt persönlich relevant und begehrenswert zu machen. Wenn jemand (oder etwas) auf dich (sehnsüchtig ) wartet, übt es einen positiven emotionalen Druck auf den prospektiven Kunden aus. Das semantisch korrekte und ehrliche:  "Die Karte ist fertig und wir wollen, dass Sie sie abholen." hat den gegenteiligen emotionalen Effekt. Es wird bestenfalls eine lästige Aufgabe. Mit Worten positive Emotionen zu wecken ist Teil des Arsenals der Dichter - und Werbeschreiber sind Dichter im weitesten Sinne. Meine Antwort: Semantisch kann eine Karte nicht "warten" aber der Ausdruck ist bewusst evokativ gewählt. In der Poesie wären viele Ausdrücke semantisch zu kritisieren. Das macht Poesie nicht "falsch" oder wertlos. Sprache hat mehr Funktionen, als Informationen grammatikalisch und semantisch korrekt zu übermittleln.

Answer (score 12):

Kurz ein literarisches Zitat, das beweist, dass "Dinge auch warten können" (und sogar noch mehr, sie können sogar "werben"...):

> Auch der Baum, auch die Blume warten nicht bloß auf unsere Erkenntnis.
>
> Sie werben mit ihrer Schönheit und Weisheit aller Enden um Verständnis.
>
> *Christian Morgenstern*

Es gibt auch einen schönen Filmtitel

> Der Himmel soll warten (Heaven can wait)

der zeigt, dass Dinge auch in anderen Sprachen warten können.

Auch der Ausdruck

> ...da brauchen wir erstmal nichts zu tun - das kann warten

den man gerne nutzt, um sich vor Arbeit zu drücken, zeigt, dass in der heutigen Alltagssprache Dinge durchaus warten können.

Im heutigen Sinne ist "warten" einfach "da sein und nichts tun" - Die ursprüngliche mittelhochdeutsche Bedeutung ist allerdings "aufpassen" - Heute noch zu sehen am *Hovawart*, dem "Hof-Wächter" (eine Hunderasse). Damit tut sich eine Plastikkarte etwas schwer, da gebe ich dir recht.

Ich bin allerdings auch der Meinung, dass man Wendungen aus der Werbung nicht unbedingt allzu ernst nehmen sollte. Sie wollen mit ungewöhnlicher Sprache Aufmerksamkeit erregen, "locken" und ins Gedächtnis eingehen. Für einen heutigen Werbetexter dürfte eine "wartende Karte" noch das kleinste sprachliche Kunststück und damit beinahe schon kalter Kaffee sein.

Comment: Den "Wart" in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung (Zeugwart, Platzwart, usw.) gibt es ja auch weiterhin.

Um aus dem Englischen zu Schöpfen: _Vienna waits for you_ wurde gerade als _Wien wort auf di_ von Granda neu interpretiert (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqqE1sUPxlI).

Comment: Die ursprüngliche mittelhochdeutsche Bedeutung von "Warten" eklärt die Beziehung zwischen "Warten" (wait) und "Wartung" (maintenance).

Comment: Wendungen aus Werbung haben das Zeug dazu, sich wegen der hohen Frequenz rasch ins Alltagsdeutsch einzuschleichen und es dadurch zu verändern. So harmlos sind sie also keineswegs. (An »So muss Technik« hat man sich schon so gewöhnt, dass man auch an »Sie kann Kanzler« nichts mehr findet)

Comment: Noch schlimmer - es heißt ja "Soo! Muss Technik". Also darüberhinaus noch sinnlos eingestreute Satzzeichen.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Was soll das heißen, "Soo! Muss Technik"?? Ich verstehe das nicht.

Comment: Ich verstehe das auch nicht. Da musst du Saturn fragen. Es ist deren Slogan.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: http://www.pctipp.ch/fileadmin/media/bilder/2012/74183.jpg

Answer (score 5):

Ich glaube, dass man Ausdrücke aus dem Marketing nicht auf die Goldwaage legen sollte. Aber ganz allgemein ist "... wartet auf Sie" [nicht gerade selten](https://www.google.at/search?q=%22wartet%20auf%20sie%22&oq=%22wartet%20auf%20sie%22) und wird auch für Gegenstände, Ort udgl. verwendet die, streng genommen, selbst nicht warten können. Ich halte es für eine Kurz- oder Alternativform zu "**er**wartet Sie".

Comment: Wenn mich eine Karte *erwarten* würde, wäre das auch nicht viel besser. Wen A B erwartet, schwingt da mit, dass A ein ganz bestimmtes Gefühl in Bezug auf B hat, nämlich Sehnsucht. Solche Gefühle traue ich einer Karte nich weniger zu als die Fähigkeit Ereignisse wahrzunehmen.

Answer (score 0):

Man sagt auch, man warte auf etwas, wenn man dieses herbeisehnt. Daraus folgt keine Absicht, darauf zu reagieren. Man kann beispielsweise auf seinen eigenen Tod warten.

Was die Karte anbelangt, hoffe ich, dass Du sie bald bestellst, damit sie sich nicht grämt. Natürlich kann sie das nicht wirklich tun, aber Sprache kann dieses Bild hervorrufen und damit bei einigen Menschen eine emotionale Reaktion anregen. Das wollte der Texter wohl, nur ist es bei Dir nicht gelungen.

Comment: Gerade das Warten auf den Tod habe ich als eines der Beispiele beschrieben, die belegen, dass man da eben sehr wohl etwas tut. Bitte lies erst die ganze Frage bevor du darauf antwortest. Die Frage lautete übrigens: »Können Gegenstände warten?« bzw. »Ist meine Definition [*des Begriffs ›Warten‹*] zu eng gefasst?«) Ich kann nicht klar erkennen, an welcher Stelle dein Posting diese Frage beantwortet.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, ich habe mich auf "Kann man auch auf etwas warten, ohne die Bereitschaft zu haben, selbst auf das Eintreten des erwarteten Signals mit irgendwelchen Aktivitäten zu reagieren?" bezogen. Ich habe nicht Deine gesamten Ergüsse gelesen.

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke die Frage ist eigentlich weit off topic, denn sie ist mehr philosophisch als sprachlich-semantisch.
Ich denke aber schon, dass Dinge *im übertragenen Sinne* "warten" können. Maschinen können in *Wartelage* stehen, in "stand-by" was man auch mit "Bereitstellung" übersetzen könnte. Können Dinge "bereit" sein?
Wenn Dinge nicht "warten" könnten, dann muss man sich auch die Frage stellen ob Tiere warten können. Natürlich, werden die meisten antworten. Dann kommt die nächste Frage: ob Insekten, Mikroben und Pflanzen warten können. Die Pflanzen warten ja im Winter auf den Frühling. Können Roboter warten? Vielleicht könnte eine "Smart Card" warten?

Ergänzung: Im Beispiel könnte man die Verwendung des Wortes "warten" in Frage stellen, aber ich glaube, dass alle, die es lesen, auch verstehen was gemeint ist. Wenn man in einer Sprache Wörter und Begriffe nicht mehr im übertragenen Sinne verwenden kann und die Bedeutungen festgenagelt sind, ist die Sprache m.M.n zum Tode verurteilt. Sogar im Lateinischen werden heute Neuschöpfungen und neue Verwendungen alter Wörter erfunden. Man muss nicht die Neuerungen mögen, sie sind aber halt da und wir müssen mit ihnen umgehen.

Comment: Du gehst diese Frage viel philosophischer an, als ich sie gestellt habe. Natürlich kann man über alles philosophieren, daran ist auch nichts schlechtes, aber mir ging es doch tatsächlich um eine sprachlich-semantische Frage, vergleichbar mit »Können Computer gehen?« Es geht mir darum, ob das Verb »warten«, das eine aktive Tätigkeit ausdrückt, gemeinsam mit einem Subjekt verwendet werden kann, das gar nicht fähig ist, selbsttätige Handlungen auszuüben. Genau solche Fragen sind Themen, mit denen sich die Semantik befasst.

Comment: Wenn man in einer Sprache Wörter und Begriffe nicht mehr in übertragener Sinne verwenden kann und die Bedeutungen festgenagelt sind, ist die Sprache m.M.n zum Tode verurteilt.

Comment: Da stimme ich dir zu. Hättest du etwas vergleichbares in deine Antwort geschrieben, hätte ich sie auch positiv bewertet. So kann ich nur deinen Kommentar zur Antwort bewerten.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast hab meine Antwort ergänzt. Vielleicht ist sie jetz besser?

Comment: Jein. Ja, weil du jetzt auf den übertragenen Sinn eingegangen bist, aber auch Nein, weil du mir eine unzutreffende Prämisse unterstellst. Du scheinst zu glauben, dass ich das 1. für eine Neuerung halte und 2. nicht mag und stattdessen die Bedeutung festnageln möchte. Vor allem der zweite Punkt trifft nicht zu. Ich will keine Bedeutungen festnageln (das könnte ich nicht einmal wenn ich es wollte) und vor allem will ich niemandem verbieten, Begriffe im übertragenen Sinn zu verwenden. Aus deiner Antwort lese ich aber heraus, dass du genau das annimmst.

Comment: (Forts.:) Meine Frage lautete nicht »Ist es gut oder schlecht, von wartenden Gegenständen zu schreiben?«, sondern sie lautete: »Können Gegenstände warten?« bzw. »Ist meine Definition [des Begriffs ›Warten‹] zu eng gefasst?«